# Es posible definir la ruta de destino al guardar un archivo .csv en python3.XX

Tags: python, csv

Sin necesidad de abrir un archivo .csv, necesito generar un nuevo documento csv. y al programar que se guarde, éste se aloje en una ruta de destino definida por el usuario.

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask]. Tu pregunta al menos para mí es poco clara, las rutas de un archivo se definen siempre al abrir este, no entiendo cuando dices "Sin necesidad de abrir.."

Comment: Mi interesa crear un archivo .csv y guardar dato en el. Sin embargo lo que he encontrado en los foros es que un archivo .csv previamente creado (forma manual), se abre con python y se guarda datos en el.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claro, `open()` admite como parámetro un nombre de fichero que puede contener rutas relativas o absolutas. Por ejemplo, `open("/home/manolo/miscosas/fichero.txt", "w")`.

El problema es si quieres que el código funcione correctamente en cualquier plataforma, ya que en algunas el separador de carpetas en una ruta es `/`, mientras que en otras es `\`.

Para que el código sea independiente de la plataforma, deberías usar las utilidades que Python te da en el módulo [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html). El ejemplo anterior sería:

```py
import os.path
import os
nombre_fichero = os.path.join(os.sep, "home", "manolo", "miscosas", "fichero.txt")
f = open(nombre_fichero, "w")
```

También puedes tener problemas si la ruta en la que intentas escribir no existe. En ese caso deberías crear las subcarpetas apropiadas, para lo que puedes usar [`os.makedirs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs)

Por último puede haber problemas si la ruta en la que intentas escribir está protegida y no tienes permisos, pero eso ya es otro asunto. Todo lo más que puedes hacer en ese caso es capturar la excepción para emitir un mensaje de error apropiado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, entiendo bien su respuesta, pero me aparece el siguiente error:  SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Estimado, funcionó. Tuve que escribir con dos \\ y así me resultó. Muchas gracias.